# DerivedData folder, is it safe to delete?

Tags: ios

I have read lots of questions about the subject, but there are also lots of different answers, and now I have a problem in my app caused from files inside this folder.
My app failed to build because of a duplicate symbol on two different files, exactly one of them is a duplicate from the other.
What is the best way to avoid the problem?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, as the issue was caused by a NSString, I have changed the name of it at one of the files, and now the app launches perfectly.
Thank you in any case.